# (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Product', which is either not installed, or is abstract Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm new in django, I faced with following error when I wanted to define two models which have foreignkey to each other . I searched about it and I find out this might happen when the models have been in two different apps, but my  models are in one app . would you please help me about this .
Thanks

ERRORS:
?[31;1mstore.Collection.featured_product: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Product', which is either not installed, or is abstract.?[0m

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    featured_product = models.ForeignKey(
        'Product', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True, related_name= '+')


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField() 
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    inventory = models.IntegerField()
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    promotion = models.ManyToManyField(Promotion)
```

Comment: I faced with this error (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Product', which is either not installed, or is abstract

Comment: why not to change it to many-to-many since both are foreign key for each other

Comment: @HusamAlhwadi well, I'm passing the course right now and I did exactly what the instructor did, but it faced with error in my code.

Answer (score 1):

really I don't think you need 2 foreign keys!, only one is enough because you can get the object in both ways..means you can just use foreign in one model, i have revised the code for your reference with some details

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255) 


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField() 
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    inventory = models.IntegerField()
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='product')
    promotion = models.ManyToManyField(Promotion)
```

now you can get all products for specific collection by (back-word):

products = collection.product.all()

Comment: thanks for your comment but can't  use your suggestion , because  the model Product is defined after model Collection,  so when I  use it  code can not Identify Product table so it must be between 2 brackets.

Comment: you are welcome, but really I don't think you need 2 foreign keys!, only one is enough because you can get the object in both ways..means you can just use foreign in one model, i have revised the code for your reference with some details